# Can I create a React Element from an HTML string or dom node/element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm retrieving an HTML string from SharePoint and need to parse and modify the data and build a react element to be displayed in my react application.

Basically, I have code (as string) returning to me in a format similar to:

```
"
<div>
    <div data-sp-canvasdataversion="1">This could be a header</div>
    <div data-sp-canvasdataversion="1"><img src="titleimage.jpg"></div>
    <div data-sp-canvasdataversion="1"><a href="pdfLink.pdf">This is a link to a PDF</a></div>
</div>
"
```

and from that I need to cycle through the children and build a new React element containing some parts of what was returned and some new parts such as

```
<div>
    <div data-sp-canvasdataversion="1">This could be a header</div>
    <div data-sp-canvasdataversion="1"><img src="titleimage.jpg"></div>
    <PDFViewer file={""pdfLink.pdf""}></PDFViewer> 
</div>
```

I was originally using dangerouslySetInnerHTML which worked to simply display the data, but now i need to remove a chunk of the html, create a react element based on the data and inject the new element back into the code. Since i'm trying to insert a component now, vanilla html won't work.

I'm able to cycle through the children by converting it to a dom node but I can't figure out how to use a dom node or element as a React Element Child.

I've tried:

```js
let element = React.createElement('div', {}, HTMLString);
```

```js
let node = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(HTMLString).firstChild;

let element = React.createElement('div', {}, node);
```

```js
let node = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(HTMLString).firstChild;
let node2 = document.createElement("div");
node2.appendChild(node);
node2 = node2.firstElementChild as HTMLDivElement;

let element = React.createElement('div', {}, node2);
```

None work as needed and give me the error `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement]).` or similar.

What i need is something like:

```js
let element = React.createElement('div'); 
let node = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(HTMLString).firstChild;

node.childNodes.forEach(child => {
    if(...//child IS NOT pdf)
        element.appendChild(child)
    else if(...//child IS pdf){
        ...
        element.appendChild(<PDFViewer file="linktopdf.pdf">)
    }
})
```

Then I would expect to be able to use that in render

```
render {
    ...
    return(
        <div className="container">
            {element}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Please let me know if this is even possible and how. The only possible solution I could think of was maybe saving the child elements as strings and using dangerouslySetInnerHTML to generate all of them but I really want to get away from using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, especially like that.

Comment: You may want to try to use `react-html-parser` https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser to convert HTML into React component and then use that for your purpose.

Comment: Not sure about parsing, but when you want to render string as raw `HTML` in react, the only API available for that is [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html?#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: Check out [react-hyperscript](https://github.com/mlmorg/react-hyperscript) example in docs. You can use the lib if you want, or just implement it from scratch using the same idea since you were able to get them into DOM nodes already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up doing what I didn't want to which is using dangerouslySetInnerHTML. If anyone comes up with a better solution, please feel free to share.

```
async getArticleComponents(data: any) {
    if (!data)
        return null;

    let slides = []
    let node = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(data).firstChild;
    let children = node.childNodes;

    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var element = (children[i] as HTMLDivElement);
        var controlElement = element.attributes.getNamedItem("data-sp-controldata");
        var jObj = controlElement ? JSON.parse(controlElement.value) : null;

        if (jObj.controlType === 3) {
            var childEle = element.firstElementChild;
            var webPartData = childEle.attributes.getNamedItem("data-sp-webpartdata");
            var wpJObj = webPartData ? JSON.parse(webPartData.value) : null;

            if (wpJObj.title == "File viewer") {
                let ext = (/.*\.(.*)/i).exec(wpJObj.properties.file)[1].toLowerCase();
                if (ext === "pdf") {
                    var pdf = await fetch(`/api/SharePoint/GetFile?url=${encodeURIComponent(`${wpJObj.serverProcessedContent.links.serverRelativeUrl}`)}`)
                    .then(res => res.text())
                    .then(pdf => pdf ? `data:application/pdf;base64,${pdf}` : null);

                    slides.push(<PDFViewer key={jObj.id} file={{ pdf, fileName: "test" } as IPdfMeta} />);
                }
            } else
                slides.push(<div key={jObj.id} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: element.outerHTML }}></div>);
        }
        else if (jObj.controlType !== 0) {
            slides.push(<div key={jObj.id} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: element.outerHTML }}></div>);
        }
    }
    return slides;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For below React v17.0: try this [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)

For React v17.0 and above: try this [fork](https://github.com/hedgedoc/html-to-react) (thanks to @thesdev pointing that out)

Comment: Doesn't support React 17+, for that take a look at this fork https://github.com/hedgedoc/html-to-react instead.